# CGI and Content-Type: text/html

Tags: python, cgi

I print some text after my CGI script finishes. 
As I understand the following line is compulsory:

```
 print('Content-type: text/html\n\n')
```

apparently for the server to know that it must output HTML?

However, what solution would you suggest to make it invisible on the output page?

even if after that print i add:

```
print("<HTML>")
...
print("</HTML>")
```

the content type is printed after the html tag like regular text

EDIT. full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi
import cgitb
import sys
import subprocess
import os
import threading
import myModule

cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
a1= form['a1'].value
a2=form['a2'].value
a3=form['a3'].value


print('Content-type: text/html\n\n')
print('<html><head></head><body>')

pid=os.fork()
if(pid==0):
    print('<div align="center" > <br/><br/><br/><br/><h1>')
    infoMsg=myModule.myFun(a1,a2,a3)
    print('</h1></div></body></html>')
else:
    exit()
```

Comment: It is a head, it is *not* visible on the output page. If it's appearing, you are doing something strange, but without seeing your actual code we can't tell what.

Comment: unfortunately it is visible,. Ok sure, i edited my question and added the full code

Comment: What are you trying to hide? I didn't quite get your question.

Comment: Did you find out why? [Someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64888172/how-to-make-content-type-text-html-not-to-be-displayed-in-output) has the same problem