# How to make 'Content-type: text/html' not to be displayed in output?

Tags: python, html, cgi

I have a cgi python script which gets data from html form, handles it and makes
a table which put to html code.

The snip of the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cgi

print('Content-type: text/html\n')
print()
print("""<!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        # and etc.
```

When I use the form I see the new page with a table but before this table I
see the text string

```
Content-type: text/html\
```

How to change the python code for not displaying this string in browser.
Put it in comment doesn't help.

Comment: I think you need to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53912765/cgi-html-to-python)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't contain the answer on my question.

Comment: What does the network tab say the file headers are? - can you try `print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"`

Comment: The response headers are:

`Connection: keep-alive,
Content-Encoding: gzip,
Content-Type: text/html,
Keep-Alive: timeout=30,
Server: nginx-reuseport/1.13.4,
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding`,

On the server is installed python v3.

Comment: I reopened the question. There is something weird going on. What browser? Does another browser work better? Did you clean your cache? Does a plain HTML file from the same folder work? Why do you you not have a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/python3` - Does your nginx understand and parse python CGI?

Comment: For example: https://techexpert.tips/nginx/python-cgi-nginx/

Comment: I use chrome, but also tried in edge and iexplorer. All browsers work the same. I have a shebang with a path to python3, just missed it in snippet of code. When I inspect the page I see that the text string **Content-type: text/html**  was put between </head> and <body> tags. All other code of the script works fine.